# Cannot increase log level debugging in tomcat6 using jndi realm

Tags: authentication, active-directory, ldap, tomcat6

I am trying to configure tomcat to connect to an ldap database using JNDI Realm, in order to integrate with Active Directory.  However, I am getting the following error in my logs and cannot seem to increase the log level to see what is really going on.

```
Feb 19, 2014 10:10:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1048 ms
Feb 19, 2014 10:10:42 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Feb 19, 2014 10:10:42 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.36
Feb 19, 2014 10:10:42 AM org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase init
FINE: Register Realm Catalina:type=Realm,realmPath=/realm0
Feb 19, 2014 10:10:42 AM org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase start
FINE: No SingleSignOn Valve is present
Feb 19, 2014 10:11:34 AM org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase start
FINE: No SingleSignOn Valve is present
Feb 19, 2014 10:11:44 AM org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase start
FINE: No SingleSignOn Valve is present
Feb 19, 2014 10:11:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor host-manager.xml
Feb 19, 2014 10:11:45 AM org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase start
FINE: No SingleSignOn Valve is present
Feb 19, 2014 10:11:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor manager.xml
Feb 19, 2014 10:11:45 AM org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase start
FINE: No SingleSignOn Valve is present
Feb 19, 2014 10:11:45 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-80
Feb 19, 2014 10:11:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 64228 ms
Feb 19, 2014 10:11:54 AM org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase invoke
FINE: Security checking request GET /tip/
Feb 19, 2014 10:11:54 AM org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase findSecurityConstraints
FINE:   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[Secure Area]' against GET /index.jsp --> true
Feb 19, 2014 10:11:54 AM org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase findSecurityConstraints
FINE:   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[Secure Area]' against GET /index.jsp --> true
Feb 19, 2014 10:11:54 AM org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase invoke
FINE:  Calling hasUserDataPermission()
Feb 19, 2014 10:11:54 AM org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase hasUserDataPermission
FINE:   User data constraint has no restrictions
Feb 19, 2014 10:11:54 AM org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase invoke
FINE:  Calling authenticate()
Feb 19, 2014 10:11:54 AM org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase invoke
FINE:  Failed authenticate() test
```

My Realm configuration within tomcat's server.xml looks like this:  (I obviously remove sensitive information)

```
  <!-- JNDI Realm authentication start -->
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm" debug="99"
        connectionURL="ldap://<ldap server goes here>:389"
        connectionName="cn=app,ou=service admin accounts,ou=users,o=iam"
        connectionPassword="password goes here"
        referrals="follow"
        userBase="ou=fil,ou=users,o=iam"
        userSearch="(AMAccountName={0})"
        userSubtree="true"
        roleBase="ou=groups,o=iam"
        roleName="cn"
        roleSubtree="true"
        roleSearch="(member={0})"
    /> 
  <!-- JNDI Realm authentication end -->
```

My tomcat logging.properties look like this:

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more

# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with

# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.

# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0

# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with

# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

#

#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

#

# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software

# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,

# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.

# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and

# limitations under the License.



handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler



############################################################

# Handler specific properties.

# Describes specific configuration info for Handlers.

############################################################



1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = ALL

1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs

1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = catalina.

1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.bufferSize = -1



2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = ALL

2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs

2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = localhost.



3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = ALL

3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs

3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = manager.



4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = ALL

4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs

4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = host-manager.



java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = ALL

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter



############################################################

# Facility specific properties.

# Provides extra control for each logger.

############################################################

# Possible levels are: SEVERE, WARNING, INFO, CONFIG, FINE, FINER, FINEST or ALL



org.apache.catalina.realm.level = ALL

org.apache.catalina.realm.useParentHandlers = true

org.apache.catalina.authenticator.level = ALL

org.apache.catalina.authenticator.useParentHandlers = true



org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = ALL

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers = 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler



org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].level = ALL

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].handlers = 3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler



org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].level = ALL

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].handlers = 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler



# For example, to log debug messages in ContextConfig and HostConfig

# classes and to log only warnings and errors in other

# org.apache.catalina.** classes, uncomment these lines:

#org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.level = FINE

#org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.level = FINE

#org.apache.catalina.level = WARNING
```

So, as you can see I have tried to increase the log level by adding the debug="99" to the server.xml and change the real and authenticator levels to ALL.  However, I am still not getting anything that looks useful except for the error **Failed authenticate() test**

Where is the rest of the log information? What I am expecting is to see the LDAP query going out.

Comment: Just to be sure it's not the problem, but do you know for sure that the above logging.properties is loaded? As far as I can see, the content is correct and should give you all debug logs..

Answer (score 0):

Your setup seems right to me. So I'm wondering are you sure that there are other logs to show?

As you can see in the [JavaDocs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/catalina/docs/api/org/apache/catalina/authenticator/AuthenticatorBase.html) of this library the method authenticate is defined like this:

```
authenticate

protected abstract boolean authenticate(Request request,
                                        Response response,
                                        LoginConfig config)
                                 throws java.io.IOException
```

And described as:

> Authenticate the user making this request, based on the specified
> login configuration.
>
> Return true if any specified constraint has been
> satisfied, or false if we have created a response challenge already.
>
> Parameters: request - Request we are processing response - Response we
> are creating config - Login configuration describing how
> authentication should be performed.
>
> Throws: java.io.IOException - if an
> input/output error occurs

This means that the method will throw an error (and some log info with it) only if there is an IO error, otherwise it simply return false (probably authentication went wrong for some other reason).

So if whoever call this method does not handle the "false" case logging something meaningful but simply logging "authentication failed" can be the case that your config is well done and you cannot get additional information from this.

Answer (score 0):

I already see an issue with your configuration...

```
    referrals="follow"
    userBase="ou=fil,ou=users,o=iam"
    userSearch="(AMAccountName={0})"
    userSubtree="true"
    roleBase="ou=groups,o=iam"
```

should be

```
    referrals="follow"
    userBase="ou=fil,ou=users,o=iam"
    userSearch="(sAMAccountName={0})"
    userSubtree="true"
    roleBase="ou=groups,o=iam"
```

And, from my experience, the transactions between the the Tomcat server and the LDAP/AD server will be reflected in the **localhost.<date>.log** rather than in the **catalina...** logs.

Hope that helps.